# iPhone 6 hot, no camera, won't hold a charge

Tags: iphone

My 6-month-old iPhone 6 is hot at the top, by camera lens, won't hold a charge and the camera is just black. All other functions are normal. This started a few days ago.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What model iPhone do you have? When did this start happening?

Comment: I edited the user's responses into the question.

Answer (score 1):

When I have seen this behavior, it has been hardware failure (usually due to water damage). If your phone is less than 6 months old and you have no reason to suspect water damage, you should contact Apple at https://getsupport.apple.com/

Comment: https://getsupport.apple.com is much more helpful here because it skips the basic troubleshooting and goes right to where you can contact Apple.

Comment: Edited to reflect that